# create table with same column as csv file

Tags: csv, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have CSV file with the more than 200 columns, I wanna to import it to oracle DB with sql developer, I know the wizard part , but my question is how should I create automatically table with 200 columns ? I f I want to create it as normal wat I should add 200 columns to my table, Is it any other way ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to know the structure of the table a priori, unless the wizard can handle this for you.

Comment: Yes , I should create table manually .. :(

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to write a script in a language like Java which tries to figure out what type of each column, but in my experience I don't have a need for this usually.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Smith, SQL Developer Alpha & Omega, described both ways:

- Load into an [existing table](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/)
- Let SQL Developer [create table](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/how-to-import-from-excel-to-a-new-oracle-table-with-sql-developer/) for you

Have a look, pick an option you find the most appropriate for you situation.

Comment: they don't discuss about how to create table from CSV file automatically

Comment: That's not how I understood the OP, @soheilz92. "... my question is how should I create **automatically** table with 200 columns "